# TypeScript Ramda propOr return type

Tags: typescript, return-type, ramda.js, typescript-types

I'm composing a Redux selector with Ramda in TypeScript:

```
const getAvatar = pipe(
  getCurrentUsersProfile,
  propOr('/images/default-avatar.png', 'avatar'),
);
```

The tooltip for `getAvatar` says it returns `unknown`.

With the `prop` function I can assert a return type like this:

```
const getCurrentUsersId = pipe(
  getUserProfileSlice,
  prop<'currentUsersId'>('currentUsersId'),
);
```

How can I get it to know that `propOr` always returns a `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pipe` function excepts a list of types. The 1st type is the input of the 1st function, and the other denote the return type of each function in order. The last type is the result of the last function, and the entire pipe.

```
type Store = {}; // type of your redux store
type UserProfile = {}; // type of the UserProfile slice

const getAvatar = pipe<Store, UserProfile, string>(
  getCurrentUsersProfile,
  propOr('/images/default-avatar.png', 'avatar'),
);
```

### Old answer:

You can explicitly type the `propOr` call, and add the return value ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lw9uin?file=index.ts)):

```
import { pipe, propOr } from 'ramda';

const getCurrentUsersProfile = () => {};

const getAvatar = pipe(
  getCurrentUsersProfile,
  propOr('/images/default-avatar.png', 'avatar') as (src: any) => string,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`propOr` is, I think, fundamentally difficult to type - saying that it always returns a string would, I think, defeat the point of the function.

The function is designed to provide a fallback in case the supplied object does not have the specified property. The type of the object will satisfy one of the three conditions:

- TS can verify that it has the property
- TS can verify that it does not have the property
- TS can not verify whether or not it has the property

In either the first or second condition, TS can tell you what the type of the result of the function will be and so there's almost no point in calling a propOr - we already know that it either does or doesn't have the property we are querying.

The problem is typing for the third condition. If we are calling propOr on an object with unknown type, what type should propOr return? At best I suppose it's something like `unknown | T` which tells us nothing, really. If we can't verify that the object will have a value of type `T` at some property `K` then we can't say what the result of the function will be.

The best thing I could think to do (and I hope someone has a better suggestion) would be to supply a function which will always coerce the value at the key to the type we want, for instance in the following example (forgive the uncurried functions):

```
const hasKey = <K extends PropertyKey, T, U extends Record<K, U>>(k: K, o: any): o is U => o.hasOwnProperty(k);

const propOr = <K extends PropertyKey, T>(d: T, k: K, o: any, f: (x: any) => T) => hasKey(k, o)
  ? f(o[k])
  : f(d);


const test = propOr<'avatar', string>('/images/default-avatar.png', 'avatar', { a: 1 }, (s: any) => `${s}`);
```

In this instance, `test` is type string, but it feels very clunky. I can't think of any other way to do this with reliable types. @OriDriori's option of providing type hints will work fine but I', guessing it is forcing typescript's hand a little - propOr *may* not return a string and saying that it always will is not exactly true (though you may be totally happy to accept that practically for your code it will).

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! You said "propOr _may_ not return a string", but it always will, right? I know the object and know that the object's property if present is a string. My fallback is a string. So I'd be able to guarantee it is always a string. Even if the fallback is a different type from the prop, shouldn't there be a way to tell that to propOr? For example either this is a string or - if fallback - a number?

Comment: @J.Hesters I believe that, no, it will not always return a string - in the case that `propOr('a', 'prop', {prop: 1})` it'd return a number. In your case it may be that `getUserProfile` always returns an object that will have the property 'avatar' and that will always be type 'string', but in that case `prop` is probably a more useful function